# I am having issues creating an environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When trying to create an environment in Elastic Beanstalk I get the following errors:

Environment health has transitioned from No Data to Degraded. Auto Scaling activity failed 45 seconds ago with error: The parameter SecurityGroup is not recognized. Launching EC2 instance failed. At 2023-08-28T19:41:39Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1. There are no instances. Auto Scaling group desired capacity is set to 1.

Creating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-bmehkfmf33-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1OHMLNQLHGN5B failed. Reason: Group did not stabilize. {current/minSize/maxSize} group size = {0/1/1}. Failed Scaling Activity: The parameter SecurityGroup is not recognized. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Stack named 'awseb-e-bmehkfmf33-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].

I tried to create an environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk to host a python flask application.

Comment: can you retrieve logs? we may need more information than this.   If you can show what they say in eb-engine.log file, that would be much more helpful

Comment: same error here :'(